# scheduled task to logon to remote windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, scheduled-task

I need to start some services on another Win10 machine every day which is not available as Service, and requires that someone logs on to the windows machine. The only way to do this is to login to this win machine and then locks it.

Is there any way to create a scheduled task (on another machine) to connect and logon to remote computer?

Comment: Have you tried starting your application as a "hand made" service, for example with [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use a remote desktop connection with settings for which programs to run on the remote, note that this do require that you already are loged in on the local machine to have a desktop to render to. There might also be other RDP clients that you could run from console.

Another approach could be to have automatic logon for a separate user on the other machine using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon
And then autorun the programs and finally lock the computer.

To lock the computer use `Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

Comment: For the first suggestion, I m not sure how to do that exactly. 
And checking second suggestion.

Comment: how to lock computer automatically after certain time of login

Comment: Updated with command to lock, you do not need a timeout, but I would recommend that you use a script cmd/powershell that runs from `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` the lock command can be anywhere in there, even at the top, the rest of the commands will keep on running even if the desktop gets locked

Comment: Rather than placing a script in the start menu's startup folder, you should prefer to create a scheduled task that triggers on log on.